# Finding max value of each row in csv file

Tags: python

I need to find the largest value from each row and display the info in a certain format. The CSV file is

```
name    tribe   id  Score1  Score2  Score3  Score4

Aang    Normad  N321B   89  67  54  78

Gyatso  Omaticaya O111C 54  78  65  78
```

What I need is an output such as

```
                  Highest score

    Aang          Score1

    Gyatso        Score2, Score 4
```

So far, with the code I did, I can only display out the max score for both of the players. However, I am unsure how to go about linking the result to which Score it is under (eg Score1, Score 2). I also have no idea how to make the result appear twice such as in the case of Gyatso. Have searched online for guides but most were related to finding max of columns or advise to use pandas which I have not started learning. Beginner to python and coding in general so currently struggling with this. Will really appreciate some help, thanks

```
def display_avatar_top_elements():
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            user,tribe,id, *scores= row.values()
            if all(score.isdigit() for score in scores):
                max_score= max([int(score) for score in scores])
                print (max_score)
```

Current output

```
89
78
```

Comment: You can easily use a lambda function to find the maximum of your `scores` dictionary, check my answer below to see how @hao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get all the indexes of the maximum of an array. Try this:

```
def display_avatar_top_elements():
    with open(filePath) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            user,tribe,id, *scores= row.values()
            if all(score.isdigit() for score in scores):
                int_scores = [int(score) for score in scores]
                max_score_indexes = [i for i,score in enumerate(int_scores) if score==max(int_scores)]
                print(['Score' + str(index+1) for index in max_score_indexes])
```

Comment: er, got an error "builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'index'"

Comment: Yeah, I had a copy and paste error in there. Try again now, it should work.

Comment: yeps, it works now, the output for aang seems to be alright, but the  Gyatso one only shows Score2, leaving out Score4 which has a similar score. Mind explaining what does the last 2 lines of your code if you dont mind please?

Comment: Sure, I'll add an explanaiton

Comment: Added Explanation

Comment: tysm for the explanation!  is there any ways to output Score4 as one of the high score for Gyatsu using this current code since Score4 is considered as the second occurence of the same high score?

Comment: No Problem! Sure Thing!

Comment: @Hao I edited the code again, it should work now as you like

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking out the scores dictionary from the row, and then get the maximum key and value.

```
import csv
import operator
scores_list = []
with open('name.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #Get the dictionary with all the scores
        scores = {k:v for k,v in row.items() if 'Score' in k}
        #Calculate the maximum score on value and append it to a list
        max_scores = list(max(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))
        scores_list.append(max_scores)
print(scores_list)
```

The output will be.

```
[
['Score1', '89'], 
['Score2', '78']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
for row in reader:
    max_score = max(((sname, int(s)) for sname, s in row.items() if sname.startswith("Score")), key=lambda s: s[-1])
    print(max_score)
```